# MD5 proving collision for the famous hexadecimal blocks

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, md5

Below shows the hexadecimal pair which collides in MD5 (http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/):

d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89
55ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5b
d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0
e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70

d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab50712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89
55ad340609f4b30283e4888325f1415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbd7280373c5b
d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e23487da03fd02396306d248cda0
e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080280d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f965ab6ff72a70

I tried to convert these hexadecimal to string and convert it to MD5 using online string to MD5 generator but it seems that the MD5 hashes I got are not 79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4 and both of the MD5 hashes generated are different. May I know why is it so and is there any way I can try to prove the blocks above collides in MD5? I am a beginner in MD5.

Comment: Disclaimer, I am author of the tool. But: http://decrane.io/hex . You can try there to decode hex into the UTF8 string. There is detection if the resulting string can be created in valid form. And it turns out, it cannot (because for this binary UTF-8 does not have a representation). So I suppose that may have been your problem. Your collision works as expected when decoded property (you can try it there as well, md5 takes hex an input).

Answer (score 7):

The following is python that does what you ask.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> s1 = 'd131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f8955ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5bd8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1ec69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70'.decode('hex')
>>> s2 = 'd131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c2fcab50712467eab4004583eb8fb7f8955ad340609f4b30283e4888325f1415a085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbd7280373c5bd8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6dd53e23487da03fd02396306d248cda0e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080280d1ec69821bcb6a8839396f965ab6ff72a70'.decode('hex')
>>> s1 == s2
False
>>> hashlib.md5(s1).hexdigest() == hashlib.md5(s2).hexdigest()
True
>>> hashlib.md5(s1).hexdigest()
'79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4'
>>> hashlib.md5(s2).hexdigest()
'79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4'
```

As to why what you tried didn't work, I can only speculate. Perhaps you didn't convert the hex strings properly.

**Note:**
For Python 3, use `bytes.fromhex` to convert the hex string into a binary string.

Comment: Depending on exactly how the strings were converted from hex to binary, and that binary was transferred into the web form, they could've been mangled in any number of ways. Not all methods of transferring data are binary-safe, i.e. they may not preserve arbitrary binary strings intact. That's why these are generally published in hexadecimal -- it's much less likely to get mangled in transit. Once it's converted to binary, you need to make sure you store and transfer it only in binary-safe forms. Python can handle binary fine (in the right data type, which you used); web forms not so much.